# Passing Request to Django form Still shows self not defined

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Python and Django to make a Web Application. As my title states I am trying to pass the request down to one of my form classes so I can use user data. I know there are a lot of questions on this, but I have tried each one of them and it does not allow me to access the user parameter.

My Code:

Form Class:

```
class CreateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    super(CreateEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
image = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
location = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
ticket_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
event_owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EventOwner.objects.all().filter())
ticket_price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'category', 'event_owner', 'ticket_name', 'ticket_price', 'location']
```

My View:

```
class CreateEventView(View):
    form_class = CreateEventForm
    template_name = 'create-event.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request, request.POST)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

            # Now check to make sure the user has created an "Event Organiser" name
            eo = EventOwner.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id)

            # If there has been an event owner made
            if eo.count() > 0:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

            # Else send the user to the create event owner
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'You must have an organiser profile setup before creating an event.')
                return redirect('/create-organiser')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'You have to login before you can create an event.')
            return redirect('/login')
```

However when ever I try to use self.request it does not work. It says unresolved reference "self"

Comment: *Where* does it show that?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm so every time I try to use "self.request" it underlines it in red and says that it is a unresolved reference.

Comment: But whereabouts are you trying to use it?

Comment: I tried to just print it after the constructor in the form Class just before main. Ideally I want to use so I can do this: `queryset=EventOwner.objects.all().filter(owner_id=self.request.user.id)`

Comment: But you have to use it in a method. `self` is an argument to a method, it's not defined outside.

Comment: So I cant use it in the filter method above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136782/discussion-between-mark-barrett-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You have to use it inside one of the methods that you define in your form.

Comment: I am trying to filter the event_owner field so that the user can only choose from a list of items that relate to him i.e that are saved using his id (request.user.id)? Is this not possible

Comment: Yes of course that is possible but *you do it in the `__init__` method*.

Comment: I tried to get the queryset inside init using self.request, but I am unsure as how to use this in the rest of the form? Sorry about this, Im used to declaring a field and when an instance of the class is created, that field is updated by the constructor. I can't seem to wrap my head around why I can't instantiate a blank User object and re-assign it in the constructor so I can use it throughout the whole class.

Comment: And I can't understand why you think you can't do that. That is exactly what you should do. In the "constructor", you accept the user object and use it to filter the queryset. You can't use it outside the method because *it doesn't exist outside the method*.

Comment: I used the user object to filter the query set but when I do so I cannot access the filtered query set outside of the constructor, I get the original one. `class CreateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    event_owner_set = EventOwner.objects.all()

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(CreateEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        event_owner_set = self.event_owner_set.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    print event_owner_set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above still works no problem, but I was confusing some stuff from the **init** section. Leave **init** the way it is.

By creating a query set of all objects first and then overwriting them as follows, I was able to limit the query set by filtering it with the request.user parameter:

```
class CreateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    event_owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(CreateEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['event_owner'].queryset = EventOwner.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```